# Printing to the same console line but dynamically

Tags: python, logging

As part of my script I am printing to the console. I'd really like to print onto the same line but dynamically. e.g.

Something like

```
1, 2,

1, 2, 3,

1, 2, 3, 4
```

I have tried:

```
logging.info("Deleting rows...");
for i in range(0, sizeOfFeed):
    logging.info("\%d"  % i);
```

Put this just does

```
\0
\1
\2
```

It's dynamic but on different lines.

Any tips

Comment: I don't understand the question. What printable stuff do you have and what is the function that governs the dynamicity of the printing out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from sys import stdout
from time import sleep
for i in range(1,20):
    stdout.write("\r%d" % i)
    stdout.flush()
    sleep(1)
stdout.write("\r  \r\n") # clean up
```

\r is a special char: carriage return, in old typing machine it locate the cursor at the begin of line

Comment: Thanks. I note stdout must be used and print, logging go to the next line. Is there anyway to get this working with the logging module?

Comment: I think you can't, but you can use the stderr for logging

Comment: logging can print to stdout, stderr, files... even all at the same time - you just need to add the proper handlers

Answer (score 4):

Store the line to be printed. Print a `\r` then the line, then flush. Change the line, then repeat.

Comment: Works for me (although the OP will have to take care not to print a trailing newline).